# SwiftUI App Crashing EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when coredata list items are deleted

Tags: macos, core-data, swiftui, runtime-error

The following code is working all the way until the delete operation is done on list items. But this is not occurring every time the code is running. It crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` code of thread error:

[image: ERROR]

Then I realized, this error is occurring after a certain time after delete operation if the app is kept running

This is why this error is very confusing to figure out. But it started appearing when I added `DispatchQueue.main.async` method to `tasks` in `Model.swift`.

The purpose of this code is to reload updated results from core data using `self.fetchAll()` method when there is any change happened in the list.

[image: Red Line on Delete]

Another problem I noticed is the red lines appearing after deleting.

Questions:

1. How to update content view struct with least code when a core data list is updated? (This [link](https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/CoreData-MacOS) has a different approach by the fetch method is called every time explicitly in code.)
2. How to optimize this code with less code and more stability?
3. Is the red line issue from the picture is part of an existing macOS bug?

> macOS: 10.15.4
>
> XCode: 11.5
>
> Target: 10.15

**Model.swift**

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var context: NSManagedObjectContext
    @Published var tasks: [Task] = [Task]() {
        didSet {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.fetchAll()
            }
        }
    }
    init(_ viewContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        context = viewContext
    }
}

// MARK: Methods

extension Model {
    func fetchAll() {
        let req = Task.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Task>
        req.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.name, ascending: true)]
        do {
            self.tasks = try self.context.fetch(req)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func addTask(_ text: String) {
        let name = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        if (name != "") {
            let task = Task(context: self.context)
            task.id = UUID()
            task.name = name
            task.creationTimestamp = Date()
            task.updatedTimestamp = Date()
            self.context.insert(task)
            self.save()
        }
    }
    
    func save() {
        guard self.context.hasChanges else { return }
        do {
            try self.context.save()
            print("Saved changes")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    var window: NSWindow!
    var model: Model!
    
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        
        model = Model(persistentContainer.viewContext)
        let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(model)

        window = NSWindow(
            contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window")
        window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
        window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) { }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "Todo_List")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        container.viewContext.undoManager = nil
        container.viewContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = true
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving and Undo support

    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext

        if !context.commitEditing() {
            NSLog("\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))) unable to commit editing before saving")
        }
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                NSApplication.shared.presentError(nserror)
            }
        }
    }

    func windowWillReturnUndoManager(window: NSWindow) -> UndoManager? {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext.undoManager
    }

    func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        if !context.commitEditing() {
            NSLog("\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self))) unable to commit editing to terminate")
            return .terminateCancel
        }
        
        if !context.hasChanges {
            return .terminateNow
        }
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            let result = sender.presentError(nserror)
            if (result) {
                return .terminateCancel
            }
            
            let question = NSLocalizedString("Could not save changes while quitting. Quit anyway?", comment: "Quit without saves error question message")
            let info = NSLocalizedString("Quitting now will lose any changes you have made since the last successful save", comment: "Quit without saves error question info");
            let quitButton = NSLocalizedString("Quit anyway", comment: "Quit anyway button title")
            let cancelButton = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button title")
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = question
            alert.informativeText = info
            alert.addButton(withTitle: quitButton)
            alert.addButton(withTitle: cancelButton)
            
            let answer = alert.runModal()
            if answer == .alertSecondButtonReturn {
                return .terminateCancel
            }
        }
        return .terminateNow
    }
}
```

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    @State var taskName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack{
                TaskList()
                    .padding(.top,31)
                VStack(spacing:0){
                    TextField("New Task", text: self.$taskName, onCommit: {
                        self.model.addTask(self.taskName)
                        self.taskName = ""
                    })
                        .padding(5)
                    Divider().offset(y:-1)
                        Spacer()
                }
                if model.tasks.isEmpty {
                    Text("Nothing To Do\nPlease add something To Do.")
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 200, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .onAppear{
            self.model.fetchAll()
        }
    }
}
```

**TaskList.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    
    @State var selection: Task?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: self.$selection){
            ForEach(self.model.tasks, id: \.self) { task in
                TaskRow(task: task).tag(task)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: onDelete)
        }
    }
    
    private func onDelete(with indexSet: IndexSet) {
        indexSet.forEach { index in
            let task = self.model.tasks[index]
            self.model.context.delete(task)
        }
        self.model.save()
    }
}
```

**TaskRow.swift**

```
struct TaskRow: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    var dateString: String {
        if let timestamp = task.updatedTimestamp {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateStyle = .long
            formatter.timeStyle = .medium
            return formatter.string(from: timestamp)
        } else {
            return "No date recorded"
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(get: { () -> Bool in
                return self.task.checked
            }, set: { (enabled) in
                self.task.checked = enabled
                self.task.updatedTimestamp = Date()
                self.model.save()
            })){
                Text("")
            }
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text(task.name ?? "Unknown Task").font(.system(size: 20))
                    Spacer()
                }
                HStack {
                    Text(dateString).font(.system(size: 10)).bold()
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are saying that the crash only appear a couple of time after the deleting, it might has to do something with iCloud sync as you are using a CloudContainer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Task` is an Identifiable:

```
extension Task: Identifiable {
}
```

If you dont know you should be able to do this in your `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(self.model.tasks) {task in
}
```

I've actually had this issue as well. The workaround I had to do was to add a field `isDeleted` instead of actually deleting the record off CoreData. Then you can either clean it up later, when app is on background or terminated. or just keep the record in Coredata.

Comment: Tried it. But still crashing same way.

Comment: I have had to add the valve `contactIsDeleted` to my CoreData model as a Bool and turn it on and off due to the list crashing when a contact was deleted. I changed my list to this `if !$0.contact_isDeleted {UserRow(user: $0, property: $0.contactID)}` I tried adding `property: property` as I saw in another post but this only helped when the list cell was not visible on the screen at the time.

Answer (score 0):

As I had similar problems I could fix recently, I thought I will give your example a try. I'm not sure if your problem persists, as the question is already 5 months old without being answered.

In short: Yes, you can fix it. But you will have to work with SwiftUI and not against it. This means: Your model can provide the fetch request but you should not execute the fetch yourself. Let SwiftUI handle this for you.

Here are the required changes:

1. AppDelegate.swift

You should add your managed object context into the SwiftUI environment when creating ContentView:

```swift
let contentView = ContentView()
   .environmentObject(model)
   .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistentContainer.viewContext)
```

2. Model.swift

Remove your `tasks` published property and the `fetchAll` function. We will let SwiftUI handle this.

3. ContentView

Remove the call to `model.fetchAll()` and the check for the `model.tasks.isEmpty`, as the ContentView doesn't know anything about the tasks.

4. TaskList

Add `FetchRequest` to create your `tasks` property and add here the check for the `tasks.isEmpty`. Here is the code:

```swift
struct TaskList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var tasks: FetchedResults<Task>

    @State var selection: Task?

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        if tasks.isEmpty {
            Text("Nothing To Do\nPlease add something To Do.")
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.headline)
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
        else {
            List(selection: $selection){
                ForEach(tasks, id: \.id) { task in
                    TaskRow(task: task).tag(task)
                }
                .onDelete(perform: onDelete)
            }
        }
    }

    private func onDelete(with indexSet: IndexSet) {
        indexSet.forEach { index in
            let task = tasks[index]
            self.model.context.delete(task)
        }
        self.model.save()
    }
}
```

Using this approach did work for me nicely.
Also the delete animation is now working and drawing as it should.